# Python nose unit tests generating too many clients already

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyramid, psycopg2, nose

I'm using python 3.3, pyramid, sqlalchemy, psygopg2. I'm using a test postgres db for the unit tests. I have 101 unit tests set up for nose to run. On test 101 I get:

> nose.proxy.OperationalError: (OperationalError) FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already

It seems from the traceback that the exception is being thrown in

> ......./venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.2-py3.3.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 368, in __connect
>
> ```
>    connection = self.__pool._creator()
> ```

Perhaps tearDown() is not running after each test? Isn't the connection pool limit for Postgresql 100 at one time?

Here's my BaseTest class:

```
class BaseTest(object):
    def setup(self):
        self.request = testing.DummyRequest()
        self.config = testing.setUp(request=self.request)
        self.config.scan('../models')
        sqlalchemy_url = 'postgresql://<user>:<pass>@localhost:5432/<db>'
        engine = create_engine(sqlalchemy_url)
        DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
        DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
        Base.metadata.bind = engine
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        self.dbsession = DBSession

    def tearDown(self):
        testing.teardown()
```

My test classes inherit from BaseTest:

```
class TestUser(BaseTest):
    def __init__(self, dbsession = None):
        if dbsession:
            self.dbsession = dbsession
    
    def test_create_user(self):
        ......
        ......
```

One of the test classes tests a many-to-many relationship, so in that test class I first create the records needed to satisfy the foreign key relationships:

```
from tests.test_user import TestUser
from tests.test_app import TestApp
class TestAppUser(BaseTest):
    def __init__(self, dbsession = None):
        if dbsession:
            self.dbsession = dbsession
    
    def create_app_user(self):
        test_app = TestApp(self.dbsession)
        test_user = TestUser(self.dbsession)
        test_app.request = testing.DummyRequest()
        test_user.request = testing.DummyRequest()
        app = test_app.create_app()
        user = test_user.create_user()
        ......
```

I'm passing the dbsession into the TestApp and TestUser classes...I'm thinking that is the source of the problem, but I'm not sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This type of speculative debugging is horrible for stackoverflow's QA format. It appears as if you aren't properly closing your connections.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel: I apologize for "speculative debugging". I'm not really sure how else to word the question/issue I'm experiencing. In regards to properly closing the connections...shouldn't the `tearDown()` function properly close the connection?

Comment: The issue is how you've approached the problem on SO, which is also making it difficult to answer for anyone. I'd suggest reformulating it as a "here's the relevant code, what I have done and here's the error". You haven't shown us any of your code so there's no possible way for us to help. `tearDown` doesn't do anything that you didn't put in there so how I can say what it's doing right now?

Comment: Okay, I'll update my post and add code to it, and further elaborate. Also, I don't understand why you say "`tearDown` doesn't do anything that you didn't put in there"...it's a built in in function within the pyramid testing framework: "Undo the effects `pyramid.testing.setUp()`. Use this function in the `tearDown` method of a unit test that uses `pyramid.testing.setUp()` in its `setUp` method." [pyramid.testing](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/testing.html)

Comment: Sorry but you weren't clear to which `tearDown` you were referring (again, need code). Basically every python testing framework allows the user to override a `tearDown` method to define their own operations. Pyramid's `tearDown` works on pyramid, but unfortunately for you pyramid has nothing to do with sqlalchemy.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel: Yeah, I figured this was more a sqlalchemy issue than a pyramid issue, but I guess I'm under the assumption that `testing.teardown()` properly closes the connection to the database after each test, and therefore, I shouldn't be receiving the "too many clients" error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyramid has nothing to do with SQLAlchemy. There is nowhere in Pyramid's API where you would link any of your SQLAlchemy configuration in a way that Pyramid would actually care. Therefore, Pyramid's `testing.tearDown()` does not do anything with connections. How could it? It doesn't know they exist.

You're using scoped sessions with a unit test, which really doesn't make a lot of sense because your unit tests are probably not threaded. So now you're creating threadlocal sessions  and not cleaning them up. They aren't garbage collected because they're threadlocal. You also aren't manually closing those connections so the connection pool thinks they're still being used.

Is there a reason you need the `ZopeTransactionExtension` in your tests? Are you using the `transaction` package in your tests, or `pyramid_tm`? In a test if you don't know what something does then it shouldn't be there. You're calling `create_all()` from your `setUp()` method? That's going to be slow as hell introspecting the database and creating tables on every request. Ouch.

```
class BaseTest(object):
    def setUp(self):
        self.request = testing.DummyRequest()
        self.config = testing.setUp(request=self.request)
        self.config.scan('../models')
        sqlalchemy_url = 'postgresql://<user>:<pass>@localhost:5432/<db>'
        self.engine = create_engine(sqlalchemy_url)
        Base.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)
        self.sessionmaker = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.sessions = []

    def makeSession(self, autoclose=True):
        session = self.sessionmaker()
        if autoclose:
            self.sessions.append(session)

    def tearDown(self):
        for session in self.sessions:
            session.close()
        self.engine.dispose()
        testing.teardown()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. After trying your code, I noticed that the problem was still there. I tried passing `echo_pool=True` in `create_engine` and viewing the logs. I noticed that the `session.close()` was being called. So I then tried adding `self.engine = engine` in `setUp`, then in `tearDown` I did `engine.dispose()`, and that fixed the problem.